# How to change learning rate of MomentumOptimizer in tensorflow

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network, implementation

I am trying to implement VGG-16 architecture in TensorFlow.

As mentioned in the paper, they changed the learning rate 3 time during their 74 epochs of training.

```
def optimizer(lr):
    return tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate = lr)
```

But when I tried to change the learning rate in tensorflow,

```
lr=lr/10
opt_momentum = optimizer(lr)
opt = opt_momentum.minimize(cost)
```

I get the following error

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use 
uninitialized value fully_connected_2/biases/Momentum_1
```

I use `builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)` to save the model.

However. I can't understand how to load the trained weights to initialize the layers after changing the `learning_rate`?

For changing the learning, I am calling the function `optimizer` with a new learning rate as argument, which is return me a new `op` but the error says that the layers are uninitialized.